# Getting rid of "Current pending sector" in Microsoft dynamic drive member without resynching to another disk and erasing it

Tags: windows, software-raid, smart, chkdsk, dynamic-disk

I've got an issue with drive - current "current pending sectors" count is equal 15. I think that it might be only a result of a broken SATA cable, which I've got rid of today.

Long story short - drive was attached to faulty cable and sectors become counting. After adding another disk, cable was switched to another disk and the 2nd good disk started to become missing in disk manager and finally volume become broken.

I've ended with 2 "faulty drives" in 3x 4Tb raid5 volume and tried to repair my raid.

Finally, it started to repair, but it became clear that disk with pending sectors was chosen by windows to use as one of two source drives... 
3rd drive with good smart was cleared from raid and dynamic drive at all

But, despite my fear, the whole volume resynced without any issue within a few hours with a speed of 200mb/s read from both drives (including that with pending sectors) and write of 200mb/s to new drive.

Smart in that faulty disk by smart measures is the same as before, 15 pending sectors, not even one relocated, doesn't that means, there when it was rebuilding it was already fully read and should easily get clean smart after zero filling?

By my experience, when I've got job with access to many defected drives, which I have repaired from such pending sectors conditions and could simply get them for free, I've tried many times with many successes and long working disks, so I'm quite sure that indicator is result of that faulty SATA cable :)

But there is a question - is it possible to somehow get rid of those sectors by for example `chkdsk /r /f`? Or is there another way?

I don't want to be forced to connect yet another disk, unplug that "faulty", resync again, zero fill drive and again unplug that 4th drive and another resync... I don't want to do so mainly because my 4th drive is 6tb 5200rpm with 23k hours, and all 3 of my 4Tb drives are matching size and, what is even more important, they're 7200 with around 7k hours. And even, when I'll get rid of those sectors I'll have to resync volume to that 4tb which was missing few times, but has clear smart, but with method to clear them without zero-filling I'm way closer to desired state of 3x same 4tb as before got issues with that cable :)

Comment: It's unlikely pending sectors are result of a faulty cable.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen - that was last thing that could be wrong and happens to be the issue, after changing cable raid5 was rebuild using that particular drive, moreover current pending sectors went down to 0 from 15 after `dd` with `oflag=direct` flag.

Comment: no, current pending went away because you zeroed the drive using dd.

Answer (score 0):

If the disk is corrupted, then you have no choice but to recover the data and/or fix it.  If its not damaged, no harm will be done.  I would

- Run `chkdsk /scan /r`  to see if there are any errors
- If there are, then decide if you want to back up or not and run `chkdsk /r /f`
- If its still not fixed then run it off-line with `chkdsk /scan /forceofflinefix`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) Because of amount of data to be read, I've chosen to skip /scan /r and I've run /r /f... Will it get rid of those pending sectors assuming there won't be any issues during the scan and assuming the whole surface is ok as I'm thinking? Or is /scan different only by being "read only" and does not ask for disk unmount after start? Or is it somehow better in my case?
I don't need access to my data just now, and I want to end everything as fast as possible ;) And of course it will be faster when not mounted, so I don't mind if it's accessible during scan...

Comment: And one more thing, /forceofflinefix will do anything more, than asking for an unmounting drive in case it is used by any process? And is it helpful at all in my case when my drive already become unmounted after issuing /r /f ? Or is it that forceofflinefix is some kind of "deeper scan" not only a command related to unmounting drive?

Comment: `chkdsk /r` includes `/f`.

Comment: Unfortunately chkdsk didn't help, however after `dd if=/dev/zero bs=8M of=/dev/sdb oflag=direct ` current pending sector went down to 0 from 15 :)